# SQL Update table 1 Valid Flag if Records in table2

Tags: sql

I need to update a valid flag in table 1 to N only if there are records in table 2 and looking for the best way to write this. I was thinking something like:

```
Update table1
    Set validflag = 'N'
    Where (select count(*) from table2 > 0)
```

But doesn't look like that will do it so hoping someone has some better SQL

Comment: MySQL is not the same as SQL Server (MSSQL)

Comment: i removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a curious thing to do -- because all rows in `table1` will be updated.

Your method works, but I would recommend `exists` over an aggregation query for performance reasons:

```
Update table1
    Set validflag = 'N'
    Where exists (select 1 from table2);
```

Comment: Topicstarter the reason why Gordon recommends this for performance is that `EXISTS(..)` only needs to check one record in the table where `COUNT(*)` needs to scan the complete table when using InnoDB..